# How do I get these JavaScript buttons to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a JavaScript chatbot library. Certain commands change the buttons available (for example when you initiate the "test command" these options become available: yes, no, & cancel)

When you hit cancel it puts the original buttons back like I intended, but they aren't clickable? How can I make them clickable again?

```
var commands = [
  "test command",
  "clear messages"
];

function message(status, message) {
  if (status == "sent") {
    $(".messages").append("<div class='message sent'><p>" + message + "</p></div>");
  } else {
    $(".messages").append("<div class='message from'><p>" + message + "</p></div > ");
  }
  $(".messages").animate({
    scrollTop: $('.messages').prop("scrollHeight")
  }, 500);
}

function buttons(commands) {
  $(".buttons").html("");
  $.each(commands, function(index, value) {
    var id = value.split(" ").join("-");
    $(".buttons").append('<div class="button" id ="command_' + id + '">' + value + '</div>');
  });
}
buttons(commands);
$("#command_test-command").click(function() {
  message("sent", "test command");
  var parameters = [
    "yes",
    "no",
    "cancel"
  ];
  buttons(parameters);
  $("#command_yes").click(function() {
    message("sent", "yes");
    message("from", "you said yes");
  });
  $("#command_no").click(function() {
    message("sent", "no");
    message("from", "you said no");
  });
  $("#command_cancel").click(function() {
    message("sent", "cancel");
    message("from", "you said cancel");
    buttons(commands);
  });
});
$("#command_clear-messages").click(function() {
  $(".messages").html("");
});
```

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment because I lost sight of the issue for a moment, but you are indeed destroying the elements and creating new ones without doing any handler binding after that. This only happens in the `cancel` handler.

Comment: So why do all this destroying and recreating of elements? Seems like a more practical approach would be to create two groups of elements, `commands` and `parameters`, and just show/hide each group as needed. Then you only create them once and bind event handlers to them once.

Comment: In all fairness this is my first JavaScript project. I don't really know how to do what you're suggesting. Thanks though I'll try to research your suggestions.

Comment: Just for educational purposes, here's an alternate way to do what it seems you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/o3e1uynd/ It avoids the destructive approach of constantly destroying nodes in the DOM structure that you still ultimately want to use.

Comment: If I wanna add more commands to your code what do I do?

Comment: Are they pre-defined groups of commands?

Comment: Or maybe you meant more commands to the "commands" group? Not sure which you're referring to.

Comment: Well I list commands like command1,command2,command3,etc.. some of them have their own buttons and some don't.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure exactly what you need. For either of the groups, you can add more objects to the array that gets passed to `create`. Or you can add more calls to `create` with new groups. If this is about simply adding more nodes to the groups you create for display or other purposes, that's a bit bigger of a topic.

Comment: I mean like if I wanted test command, test command 2, clear messages, and so on. I can optionally give a command it's own buttons or keep the original ones there. (Because some commands need you to click a button to do stuff, while others do something as soon as you click them). Nonetheless you've given me a really good piece of code to build off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend setting html with js but this should trigger the click

```
$(".buttons").on('click','#command_test-command',function() {
    // test-command
});
$(".buttons").on('click','#command_clear-messages',function() {
    // clear messages
});
```

For your example

```
var commands = [
  "test command",
  "clear messages"
];

function message(status, message) {
  if (status == "sent") {
    $(".messages").append("<div class='message sent'><p>" + message + "</p></div>");
  } else {
    $(".messages").append("<div class='message from'><p>" + message + "</p></div > ");
  }
  $(".messages").animate({
    scrollTop: $('.messages').prop("scrollHeight")
  }, 500);
}

function buttons(commands) {
  $(".buttons").html("");
  $.each(commands, function(index, value) {
    var id = value.split(" ").join("-");
    $(".buttons").append('<div class="button" id ="command_' + id + '">' + value + '</div>');
  });
}

$(".buttons").on('click','#command_test-command',function() {
  message("sent", "test command");
  var parameters = [
    "yes",
    "no",
    "cancel"
  ];
  buttons(parameters);
}).on('click','#command_clear-messages',function() {
    $(".messages").html("");
}).on('click','#command_yes',function() {
    message("sent", "yes");
    message("from", "you said yes");
}).on('click','#command_no',function() {
    message("sent", "no");
    message("from", "you said no");
}).on('click','#command_cancel',function() {
    message("sent", "cancel");
    message("from", "you said cancel");
    buttons(commands);
});

buttons(commands);
```

Comment: The yes, no, and cancel buttons work. It's when you hit cancel and the original buttons come back (those don't work).

Comment: Check https://epicmc.us/chat.html (the buttons work now but... now when I hit cancel and go back to the test command it sends all messages twice, and then if I do it again it sends them 3 times, and so on.

Comment: I only get a blank screen

Comment: Oh there's command buttons on the bottom of the screen using position: sticky maybe your browser isn't compatible.

Comment: Anyhow I used your code snippet for all commands even the yes, no, and cancel ones. Is that why this error is happening? Should I only use your code snippet on commands and not on their parameters?

Comment: I think the error is because everytime you click on #command_test-command you add another listener to the other buttons. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your day to fix this error for me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I updated my answer. If it helps you you may upvote it :)